# Re use gradient drawable with theme-dependent colors

Tags: android, colors, gradient, drawable, attr

In two different activities I want to use same gradient drawable but with different colors.
I think to refer gradient colors to activity theme in follow way:

I've added follow rows in attrs.xml

```
<attr name="backgroundTopColor" format="color" />
<attr name="backgroundBottomColor" format="color" />
```

in bg_gradient.xml I typed

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient 
        android:startColor="?backgroundTopColor" 
        android:endColor="?backgroundBottomColor" 
        android:angle="270" />
    <corners android:radius="0dp" />
</shape>
```

In activity theme, I've added

```
<item name="backgroundTopColor">#FFFFFFFF</item>
<item name="backgroundBottomColor">#FFFFFF00</item>
```

After application start in logcat

> 02-07 14:03:59.479: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2096): Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to color: type=0x2
>   02-07 14:03:59.479: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2096):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:326)
>   02-07 14:03:59.479: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2096):     at android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable.inflate(GradientDrawable.java:647)
>   02-07 14:03:59.479: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2096):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:788)
>   02-07 14:03:59.479: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2096):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:729)
>   02-07 14:03:59.479: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2096):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1694)
>   02-07 14:03:59.479: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2096):     ... 29 more

How I can solve this?

Thank you

NB: API level = 8

Answer (score 0):

You should use `"?attr/backgroundTopColor"` instead of `"?backgroundTopColor"` to reference your attributes.

Edit: What happens if you indirectly reference the color?  Instead of in your theme saying:

```
<item name="backgroundTopColor">#FFFFFFFF</item>
```

You do this:

```
<item name="backgroundTopColor">@color/myColor</item>
```

Then in colors.xml, you add:

```
<color name="myColor">#FFFFFFFF</color>
```

I suspect that what might be happening is that the attribute is expecting an explicit color.  At the very least, I've done exactly what you outline, except that I always indirectly reference the color rather than putting it right into my theme.

Comment: This issue was fixed recently but only in L preview: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=26251